# Python не хочет работать с файлами (PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе)

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Заметил, что Python криво работает с файлами на моем пк. Решил написать простенькую рулетку, чтобы подтвердить это. Код рулетки:

```
import os, random

num = random.randint(1, 10)
guess = int(input('Давай сыграем в игру! Выбери число от 1 до 10\n'))

if guess == num:
    print('Поздравляю с победой!!!')
else:
    os.remove('D:/py_tests')
```

При выполниении возникает данная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/JoJo/goose/ballance/files_to_edit/py_roulete.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.remove('D:/py_tests')
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'D:/py_tests'
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А что за файл такой py_tests, он точно без разрешения(.txt, .py и т.д.)? Он не открыт в какой-то программе?Запускали от админа?

Comment: Можно попробовать запустить файл от админа, или через любую программу добавить разрешение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Или такой файл не существует (может быть, он в другой папке или вы забыли добавить его расширение, например `os.remove('D:/py_tests.py')`,
- или какая-то другая программа блокирует ваш файл.
  Как точно узнать, какая, чтобы окончить ее и тем деблокировать файл?

  Для этого вы можете применить например бесплатную программу [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/).

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш комментарий! он помог разобраться в проблеме. Как я понял, по стандарту Python не может удалять папки на дисках

Comment: @жигулевскоенефильтрованное, не стоит. Да, вы правильно поняли, что `os.remove()` только для удаления **файлов**. Для удаления вашей **папки** примените `os.rmdir('D:/py_tests')`.